# Where to download files in sveltekit so that its publically accessible via url?

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, svelte, sveltekit

I have a sveltekit app that I am deploying on ec2 via elastic beanstalk. I have to build the app using `vite build` and that generates a `build/` folder.

In my actual project directory, I am downloading some files via a cron task in the `static/data` directory because those files have to be publically accessible.

My issue is that I don't want to version control these downloaded files because they would easily overwhelm github quotas. So I gitignored them.

On elastic beanstalk, I have to upload the build folder which contains the `static/` folder copied as it is in the `build/client/` directory. However since the `static/data` directory isn't version controlled, whenever I will upload the zip file(which compresses the `build/` directory on my local system), it would overwrite the data on ec2.

I couldn't find any docs or hints in sveltekit docs. So how do I do it?